# I own minecraft bedrock edition for w10, can I buy Java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've owned Minecraft bedrock edition for windows 10 for about 2 years, when trying to **buy** Java, I always run into the problem that I can't own more than one version of Minecraft.

Can I buy Java edition after buying Bedrock edition for windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no compatibility issues between Java and Bedrock editions of Minecraft on a windows computer. You may own both versions and switch between them freely on one computer. You will, however, have to pay for and download each separately.

Source: I do this on my computer at home.